# Javascript Canvas How to draw a random shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas

When the user loads the page I want to draw a random shape.
For example a circle.
When the user loads the page again I want to draw another random shape.

I know how to draw the shape but I can I let them appear randomly ?

Comment: Create a function for each shape, put these functions to an array, and call a random shape maker with a random index, random enough?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, so we get an idea about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is simply a randomize question, nothing to do with canvas, store all your shapes on an array, make the function draw from the array, and send a different array index each time.

Comment: I got my shapes in an array. How can I make a function draw a ramdom one from that array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Math.Floor` function to generate a random number, then with that random number you can use it to draw a specific shape from your array.

As you haven't provided your array I have created a very simple jsFiddle showing you an example https://jsfiddle.net/kny74wve/ Just keep pressing the run button in the top left to generate a new random number

Html

```
<canvas id="Canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

var randomShape = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

if (randomShape == 1) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(25, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.stroke();
} else if (randomShape == 2) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(200, 200, 69, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.stroke();
} else if (randomShape == 3) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(276, 255, 70, 0, Math.PI, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.fillStyle = '#0000FF';
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.stroke();
}
```